Missing modules when packing Python function into executable
I am using the rocketCEA library to build a function for analyzing rocket propulsion performance. Moreover, I have another script written in MATLAB that needs to utilize this function. Therefore, I want to package this Python script into an executable so that anyone can use it with the MATLAB script.
import sys
from rocketcea.cea_obj_w_units import CEA_Obj

def rocketCEA_model_equilibrium(oxName, fuelName, chamber_pressure, mixture_ratio, epsilon):
    C = CEA_Obj(oxName=oxName, fuelName=fuelName,
                pressure_units='Bar',
                cstar_units='m/s',
                temperature_units='K',
                density_units='kg/m^3')

    isp = C.get_Isp(Pc=chamber_pressure, MR=mixture_ratio, eps=epsilon)
    temperature = C.get_Temperatures(Pc=chamber_pressure, MR=mixture_ratio, eps=epsilon)[:]
    MolWt_gamma_throat = C.get_Throat_MolWt_gamma(Pc=chamber_pressure, MR=mixture_ratio, eps=epsilon)
    MolWt_gamma_chamber = C.get_Chamber_MolWt_gamma(Pc=chamber_pressure, MR=mixture_ratio, eps=epsilon)
    Pc_Pe = C.get_PcOvPe(Pc=chamber_pressure, MR=mixture_ratio, eps=epsilon)
    cf = C.getFrozen_PambCf(Pamb=1E-8, Pc=chamber_pressure, MR=mixture_ratio, eps=epsilon)[0]

    mw_chamber = MolWt_gamma_chamber[0]
    gamma_chamber = MolWt_gamma_chamber[1]
    mw_throat = MolWt_gamma_throat[0]
    gamma_throat = MolWt_gamma_throat[1]

    c_star = C.get_Cstar(Pc=chamber_pressure, MR=mixture_ratio)

    output = [isp, temperature, mw_chamber, gamma_chamber, mw_throat, gamma_throat, c_star, Pc_Pe, cf]
    
    return output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    oxName = sys.argv[1]
    fuelName = sys.argv[2]
    chamber_pressure = float(sys.argv[3])
    mixture_ratio = float(sys.argv[4])
    epsilon = float(sys.argv[5])

    output = rocketCEA_model_equilibrium(oxName, fuelName, chamber_pressure, mixture_ratio, epsilon)

    # Print the result in a simple format
    print(output)

I used pyinstaller to create executable file
pyinstaller --onefile rocketCEA_model_equilibrium.py

but kept getting this error when running .exe in MATLAB
Error executing Python executable:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rocketCEA_model_equilibrium.py", line 2, in <module>
    from rocketcea.cea_obj_w_units import CEA_Obj
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 384, in exec_module
  File "rocketcea\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\ASUS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI213202\\rocketcea\\_version.py'
[PYI-13844:ERROR] Failed to execute script 'rocketCEA_model_equilibrium' due to unhandled exception!

I could not figure out what went wrong with the packing process, please help me.
Thank you very much in advance.

Retry, after adding import rocketcea.

I still got the same error. What is the effect of this command line?

Does this other Q&A solve your problem? How to include dependencies from venv directory when running pyinstaller for project built in Pycharm?.
